# Problem in changing root path nginx configuration

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location, setcookie

I have a problem with nginx configuration. I need logic that sets the root folder for static pages based on cookies set based on location. After the first redirect to / from /test1 and setting the cookie, everything works as expected. But if I try to go to another path, for example /test2, the cookies are set as expected, but the path does not change.

server
`{
listen 80;
server_name test.domain;

```
location /test1 {
    add_header Set-Cookie "SESSIONIDS=test1; Path=/";
    return 302 "/";
}

location /test2 {
    add_header Set-Cookie "SESSIONIDS=test2; Path=/";
    return 302 "/";
}

location / {
    if ($cookie_SESSIONIDS = "") {
        return 502;
    }
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/$cookie_SESSIONIDS;
    index index.html;
}
```

}
`

Comment: One problem will be that the browser will cache the original response.